# Custom string replace method

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I want to a method for string replacement.

Example :

```
Cars-are-equipped-with-controls-used-for-driving-parking-passenger-comfort-and-
safety-and-controlling-a-variety-of-lights-As-of-the-2010s-controls-have-been-
added-to-vehicles-making-them-more-complex


part = "safety-and-controlling"
/* safety is fixed */

chars = "(,'')"

output = "safety(and, 'controlling')"
```

How can I do. Any idea?

Comment: You have modified your original simple question to a form that does not make any sense anymore. Please provide the full context and formulate your question better. There is no way to answer this now with such limited information.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the number of parts is equal to the length of the `chars` string, you can solve this easily using LINQ.

```
vehicle.Split('-').Zip(chars, (x, y) => x + y).Aggregate("", (x, y) => x + y);
```

Comment: Pretty nice use of linq.  Using `string.Join` may be more obvious than using `Aggregate`.

Comment: @Matthew Good point. I was debating using it instead, but thought this form was more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
var vehicleArray = vehicle.Split('-');
var output = vehicleArray[0] + "(" + vehicleArray[1] + ", " +vehicleArray[2] + "@" + vehicleArray[3] + "." + vehicleArray[4] + ")";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regex in order to find the positions of the "-".

```
string vehicle = "car-blue-diesel-ford-com-";
string chars = "(,@.)";

MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(vehicle, "-");
var sb = new StringBuilder(vehicle);
if (matches.Count != chars.Length) {
    throw new ArgumentException("Supply the right number of replacement chars");
}
for (int i = 0; i < matches.Count; i++) {
    sb[matches[i].Index] = chars[i];
}
string output = sb.ToString(); // "car(blue,diesel@ford.com)"
```

The `StringBuilder` allows you to manipulate single characters of a text in-place.

---

A very direct approach just scans the string for "-" explicitly:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder(vehicle);
for (int i = 0, c = 0; i < sb.Length && c < chars.Length; i++) {
    if (sb[i] == '-') {
        sb[i] = chars[c++];
    }
}
string output = sb.ToString();
```

Note that these two approaches never split or join strings. The second approach is especially memory efficient.